# Dice Roller in Python Not Random

Tags: python

I made a dice roller in python recently. However, the outputs seem to be fairly non-random (e.g. numbers coming up regularly twice in a row). Is this to do with my poor code or is the random.randint function not as random as it seems?

```
import random
print('Welcome to Dice Rolling simulator! \
Type "Roll" to start.')
def DiceRoll():    
    if input() == (str('Roll')):
    print(spam)
    print('Roll again?')
for i in range (50):
    spam = random.randint(1,6)
    DiceRoll()
```

Comment: A dice roller where numbers couldn't appear twice in a row would be biased, and not random. Your code doesn't look buggy.

Comment: This is completely a normal code. In real life, there are chances that same number appears twice.

Comment: randomness does not guarantee any particular order, it just provides uniform distribution, which mean all 6 numbers will appear the same number of times as the number of samples approaches infinity.

Comment: You have actually fallen for the [gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy)

Comment: why the downvote on my answer :3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to verify the randomness of your function is to call it enough times, and verify the output distribution. The following code does so.

```
import random
def DiceRoll():
    return random.randint(1,6)

hist = []
for i in range(100000):
    hist.append(DiceRoll())

for j in range(1,7):
    print("Pr({}) = {}".format(j,hist.count(j)/len(hist)))
```

This yields :

```
Pr(1) = 0.16546
Pr(2) = 0.16777
Pr(3) = 0.16613
Pr(4) = 0.16534
Pr(5) = 0.1675
Pr(6) = 0.1678
```

Which seems to be perfectly random.

Answer (score 0):

As @Arne noticed in the comments, dice rolls repeating is desired behavior in "random" rolls (in this case, pseudo-random, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't make a difference for your application).

However, if the repeats are really bothering you, it wouldn't be hard to prevent re-rolls, e.g. the following:

```
import random
print('Welcome to Dice Rolling simulator! \
Type "Roll" to start.')
spam = random.randint(1,6)
def DiceRoll(spam):    
    if input() == (str('Roll')):
    print(spam)
    print('Roll again?')
for i in range (50):
    DiceRoll(spam)
    spam2 = random.randint(1,5)
    spam = spam2//spam*(spam+1) + spam2%spam
```

Comment: In the first iteration `spam` is not defined. Also, there are much easier ways to make sure that no 2 numbers are generated.